# Updating timestamps if they fall within a specified date range

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm currently working with a table which has information about entities and their timestamps.
The schema looks like this `dat(id, created_time)`, with `id` as the primary key.

If a timestamp falls in between Saturday 1am to Monday 1am (exclusive), we'd like to replace the timestamp with Monday 1am.

I was thinking of using a case structure to find instances where the timestamp falls on Saturday and the time is greater than 1:00.00 or timestamp falls on Sunday or timestamp falls on Monday and the time is less than 1:00.00, and assign a hard coded date and time.

I figured this is a common problem and would love any tips for how to make this more streamlined or if there is a function that exists to simplify the process. Thanks!

Comment: CASE I believe would be most appropriate given various if-then-else scenario here. There is no direct function or BETWEEN clause (only supports number and strings) that can be directly used here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are a couple of way this can be done. My answers all rely on session vairable `week_start` being `7` for Sunday, and date_trunc does not support `week_iso` so there is no always safe solution.

```
alter session set week_start = 7;
```

```
SELECT
    to_char(column1,'DY HH:MI') as t
    ,dayofweek(column1)=1 AND column1::time >= '01:00'::time as sun_after_1am
    ,dayofweek(column1)=2 AND column1::time < '01:00'::time as mon_before_1am
    ,iff(sun_after_1am OR mon_before_1am, dateadd('hour', 25, date_trunc('week', column1)), column1) as iff_answer
    ,case
        when dayofweek(column1)=1 AND column1::time >= '01:00'::time 
            then dateadd('hour', 25, date_trunc('week', column1))
        when dayofweek(column1)=2 AND column1::time < '01:00'::time
            then dateadd('hour', 25, date_trunc('week', column1))
        else column1
    end as case_answer
    ,iff((dayofweek(column1)=1 AND column1::time >= '01:00'::time) OR (dayofweek(column1)=2 AND column1::time < '01:00'::time), dateadd('hour', 25, date_trunc('week', column1)), column1) as monster_iff_answer
    ,column1 between dateadd('hour', 1, date_trunc('week', column1)) 
        and dateadd('hour', 25, date_trunc('week', column1))    
FROM VALUES 
    ('2022-03-31 09:09'::datetime),
    ('2022-03-28 08:09'::datetime),
    ('2022-03-28 00:12'::datetime),
    ('2022-03-27 23:33'::datetime),
    ('2022-03-27 01:01'::datetime),
    ('2022-03-27 00:02'::datetime)
ORDER BY column1;
```

| T | SUN_AFTER_1AM | MON_BEFORE_1AM | IFF_ANSWER | CASE_ANSWER | MONSTER_IFF_ANSWER | BETWEEN_LOGIC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sun 00:02 | FALSE | FALSE | 2022-03-27 00:02:00.000 | 2022-03-27 00:02:00.000 | 2022-03-27 00:02:00.000 | FALSE |
| Sun 01:01 | TRUE | FALSE | 2022-03-28 01:00:00.000 | 2022-03-28 01:00:00.000 | 2022-03-28 01:00:00.000 | TRUE |
| Sun 23:33 | TRUE | FALSE | 2022-03-28 01:00:00.000 | 2022-03-28 01:00:00.000 | 2022-03-28 01:00:00.000 | TRUE |
| Mon 00:12 | FALSE | TRUE | 2022-03-28 01:00:00.000 | 2022-03-28 01:00:00.000 | 2022-03-28 01:00:00.000 | TRUE |
| Mon 08:09 | FALSE | FALSE | 2022-03-28 08:09:00.000 | 2022-03-28 08:09:00.000 | 2022-03-28 08:09:00.000 | FALSE |
| Thu 09:09 | FALSE | FALSE | 2022-03-31 09:09:00.000 | 2022-03-31 09:09:00.000 | 2022-03-31 09:09:00.000 | FALSE |

So there is an two tests for `dayofweek` and a `time` compare, which are OR'ed in an IFF

```
    ,dayofweek(column1)=1 AND column1::time >= '01:00'::time as sun_after_1am
    ,dayofweek(column1)=2 AND column1::time < '01:00'::time as mon_before_1am
    ,iff(sun_after_1am OR mon_before_1am, dateadd('hour', 25, date_trunc('week', column1)), column1) as iff_answer
```

then there is the CASE, which I think actually reads nicer:

```
    ,case
        when dayofweek(column1)=1 AND column1::time >= '01:00'::time 
            then dateadd('hour', 25, date_trunc('week', column1))
        when dayofweek(column1)=2 AND column1::time < '01:00'::time
            then dateadd('hour', 25, date_trunc('week', column1))
        else column1
    end as case_answer
```

then there is the IFF mashed all together, which is gross:

```
,iff((dayofweek(column1)=1 AND column1::time >= '01:00'::time) OR (dayofweek(column1)=2 AND column1::time < '01:00'::time), dateadd('hour', 25, date_trunc('week', column1)), column1) as monster_iff_answer
```

and then there is a BETWEEN that just uses DATE_TRUNC

```
 ,column1 between dateadd('hour', 1, date_trunc('week', column1)) 
        and dateadd('hour', 25, date_trunc('week', column1)) as between_logic
```

anyways, you said update, so this give me a unified result, which a SELECT or VIEW would need can be separated into a WHERE clause

```
UPDATE table_name
    SET date_time_column = dateadd('hour', 25, date_trunc('week', date_time_column ))
WHERE date_time_column BETWEEN dateadd('hour', 1, date_trunc('week', date_time_column)) 
        AND dateadd('hour', 25, date_trunc('week', date_time_column))
```